# Connecting Firebase with NativeScript

Tags: firebase, nativescript

So i installed firebase with adding the "google-services.json" in the App_Resources/Android folder.

[image]

After that i used the cli for the cmd: "tns plugin add @nativescript/firebase".
And it was successfull.

[image]

But if i try to use "firebase.firestore()" i get the message that firestore is unknown.

[image]

Yes i have ticked yes in the installation as it asked me if i want firestore.

[image]

So it should be useful but it is not.
I deleted the "firebase.nativescript.json" and run the 'npm run config' command in the android folder but it didnt help.
Then I uninstalled the plugin with "tns plugin remove @nativescript/firebase" and re-installed it.
Nothing works. Here is my fire in @nativescript:

[image]

Is there a Solution?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of text and code.  Whenever possible, copy the text into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to import `firestore` directly from `@nativescript/firebase` and access its properties that way

```js
import { firestore } from '@nativescript/firebase';

// firebase.firestore().collection('user') becomes the following line
firestore.collection('user')
```

Comment: Yes this was the Problem. Thank you so much.